# Read sitemap with XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I want to read Sitemap with XPath but it doesn't work.
here is my code :

```
private void evaluate2(String src){
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
    try{
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(src.getBytes()));

        System.out.println(src);

        XPathFactory xp_factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

        XPath xpath = xp_factory.newXPath();

        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//url/loc");

        Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);


        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

        System.out.println(nodes.getLength());


        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            items.add(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
            System.out.println(nodes.item(i).toString()); 
        }         
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Before I retrieve the remote source of the sitemap, and it's passed to evaluate2 through the variable src.
And the `System.out.println(nodes.getLength());` display 0
My xpath query is working because this query work in PHP.
Do you see errors in my code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You parse the sitemap with a namespace-aware parser (that's what `factory.setNamespaceAware(true)` does), but then attempt to access it using an XPath that does not usea namespace resolver (or reference any namespaces).

The simplest solution is to configure the parser as not namespace aware. As long as you're just parsing a self-contained sitemap, that shouldn't be a problem.

One more problem in your code is that you pass the sitemap contents as a String, then convert that String using the platform default encoding. This will work as long as your platform-default encoding matches that of the actual bytes that you retrieved from the server (assuming that you also created the string using the platform-default encoding). If it doesn't, you're likely to get a conversion error.

Answer (score 1):

I think the input has namespace. So you would have to initialize the namespaceContext for the xpath object and change your xpath with prefixes. i.e. //usr/loc should be //ns:url/ns:loc
and then add the namespace prefix binding in the namespace object.

You can find an NamespaceContext implementation available with apache common. http://ws.apache.org/commons/util/apidocs/index.html
ws-commons-utils

```
NamespaceContextImpl namespaceContextObj = new NamespaceContextImpl();
    nsContext.startPrefixMapping("ns", "http://sitename/xx");
xpath.setNamespaceContext(namespaceContextObj);
```

XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//ns:url/ns:loc");

In case you don't know what namespaces that are comming, you can get them from the document it self, but I doubt it ll be of much use. There are few how-tos here
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-nmspccontext/index.html

Comment: But the namespace coulb be different according to sitemap version no ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any errors in your code so I gues the problem is the source.
Are you sure that the source file contains this element?

Maybe you could try to use this code to parse the String in an Document

```
builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
```

Comment: If I do this and I put a `System.out.println(doc.toString());` I've the message `[#document: null]` Is it normal ?

Comment: no thats not normal. It says that you Document object is empty. SO try it with the tip of pasifal(setNameSpaceAware(false))